# How to group latest DATETIME record per day by userId?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

For the purpose of this question, I have three fields in a MySQL table: `id`, `userId`, and `loginDate` (DATETIME). I would like to return the latest record for each `userId` per day. How can I create a query to do the following in section `B` below?

#### A. Records

| id | userId | loginDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-01-01 00:05:50 |
| 2 | 7 | 2021-01-01 06:06:50 |
| 3 | 5 | 2021-01-01 06:34:50 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-01-02 06:56:76 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021-01-02 15:46:52 |

#### B. What I would expect to be returned from the query

| id | userId | loginDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 7 | 2021-01-01 06:06:50 |
| 3 | 5 | 2021-01-01 06:34:50 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021-01-02 15:46:52 |

Comment: I have no idea what you mean in the title.  A clear explanation and results are always helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results). In combination with `DATE(loginDate)` it will definitely do the work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry please see question again. I hit save accidentally without question being ready!

Comment: @astentx - Sorry please see question again. I hit save accidentally without question being ready!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks please see below.

Comment: Check my new update, sorry

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8 you can use `row_number` [analytic function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to order your timestamps inside the day in descending order, and then select the first item per group. No tricky aggregation, limiting and joins, it just assigns the number according to the order and grouping, the rest of the row is unchanged.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 1 as id, 5 as userid, timestamp '2021-01-01 00:05:50' as logindate union all
>   select 2, 7, timestamp '2021-01-01 06:06:50' union all
>   select 3, 5, timestamp '2021-01-01 06:34:50' union all
>   select 4, 3, timestamp '2021-01-02 06:56:56' union all
>   select 5, 3, timestamp '2021-01-02 15:46:52'
> )
> , rn as (
>   select a.*,
>     row_number() over(
>       partition by
>         userid,
>         date(logindate)
>       
>       order by
>         logindate desc
>     ) as __rn
>   from a
> )
> select *
> from rn
> where __rn = 1
> order by userid desc
> ```
>
> ```
> id | userid | logindate           | __rn
> -: | -----: | :------------------ | ---:
>  2 |      7 | 2021-01-01 06:06:50 |    1
>  3 |      5 | 2021-01-01 06:34:50 |    1
>  5 |      3 | 2021-01-02 15:46:52 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5af027cc9de491607ddc9d2a8d2d94c)*

Answer (score -2):

You should use `GROUP BY` with the help of some aggregate functions.

```
SELECT max(id) AS id, userId, max(loginDate) AS loginDate FROM table GROUP BY userId ORDER BY id ASC;
```

return:

```
id  userId  loginDate
2   7   2021-01-01 06:06:50
3   5   2021-01-01 06:34:50
5   3   2021-01-02 15:46:52
```

Explanation: `GROUP BY` get's confused by your query because multiple rows may match. Using the `max()` aggregate function allows us to return only the newest rows data.

Comment: But it will not produce the row "as per date end".

Comment: Sorry please see question again. I hit save accidentally without question being ready!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I tried something like this. It will not return the last distinct record by userId per day...It's returning multiples per userId.